# Big Query get first day of week

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I'm working with Big Query and I need to get first day of week.

For example if date = '2022-08-26' I want to have '2022-08-22' where 22 is Monday.

Any solutions please ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you'll want to use the `DATE_TRUNC` function as follows:

```
select date_trunc(date('2022-08-26'), WEEK(MONDAY))
```

You can change the parameter for `WEEK` to be any day of the week, default is SUNDAY.

Documentation can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_trunc